# Как узнать, входит ли символ в заданый интервал

Tags: python, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста как узнать, входит ли символ в интервал строки

```
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type == MessageEntityType.URL:
            print("URL", "".join(
                ["*" if ii in message.text[entity.offset:entity.offset + entity.length] 
                 else ii 
                 for ii in message.text]))
```

*Как должно работать:* Если индекс входит в заданый интервал `[entity.offset:entity.offset + entity.length]` то символ заменяется на `*` иначе записывается сам символ.

*Как работает:* При заданом тексте `test google.com` выводит `URL t*st **********`

В целом все работает на библиотеке `aiogram`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён.

```
async def entites(message: Message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type == MessageEntityType.URL:
            message.text = "".join([
                    "*" if (entity.offset) <= ii <= (entity.offset + entity.length -1)
                    else list(message.text)[ii]
                    for ii in range(0, len(message.text))
                ])
            list(message.entities).remove(entity)
    print(message.text)
```

### Ввод

`google.com test yandex.ru textSimple`

### Вывод

`********** test ********* textSimple`